# Std. err. of the difference vs std. err. of the mean of the difference: analogy to unpaired vs paired t-test?

Tags: t-test, mean, standard-error

Say we have this:

```
x <- c(993.354165847643, 1055.48537986726, 4003.32907924129, 494.21057245789, 4662.29695447144, 1395.13557275882, 1695.5747710304, 3622.32128274203, 4063.4847568296, 2287.35662116521, 4456.96939812236, 3929.71358024154, 1321.26970668235, 959.859904005188, 1603.04363403031, 771.34718619393, 4629.33336664729, 2926.47839689164, 618.50690152634, 3033.26379133148, 4044.42403633577, 1265.59998369787, 2790.26210957826, 4726.54044861499, 3859.63959322805, 713.827526848569, 3728.54267565127, 4105.45274632, 3695.95167122361, 3475.14471956252, 2562.88641254128, 1175.4886523273, 1541.75447052156, 915.832407495865, 547.673007369953, 2236.59291645992, 3146.57449432257, 1670.87100263699, 2482.51233266087, 4034.63492270761, 1504.03599814317, 941.986204651309, 4386.59394614236, 822.726642401517, 4694.44151337787, 4639.524036903, 1947.25926415882, 2082.9447133529, 1370.96973022059, 4065.12647993175, 3601.55660358343, 4306.7958250248, 2350.39170539696, 3983.03451820313, 3714.81427862702, 490.958533071285, 828.668876473295, 4277.73742268773, 4737.23358080266, 2559.49398515138, 1514.14896559722, 899.589848826677, 2879.26834281265, 707.436631036836, 1267.86705992644, 1456.02338405603, 3820.59709748663, 685.699352434722, 768.627494521916, 2261.18861570379, 3016.82216301372, 3665.24842754188, 1014.93406045042, 4057.44987862074, 3354.80205926634, 4379.51865630041, 3950.33150960694, 4298.62743764328, 1424.43884388634, 699.620422073228, 4650.82249781165, 2459.16668767922, 3119.16788276332, 3198.41731320632, 4380.46344770071, 1214.57226688602, 4773.93561238519, 1461.68163936954, 4076.41971845327, 4481.25959795584, 2779.16920368152, 1566.36645019419, 651.550578452552, 1180.84630356349, 1085.66035328584, 897.070174665921, 791.310827530615, 567.723239449041, 826.476263553536, 1811.53654504956, 3492.62018264507, 1115.68007513428, 3383.24442617197, 961.855945143232, 4069.8814239134, 4709.55997173359, 3756.41538322972, 2145.80891494233, 3677.48933344669, 840.104995983564, 2796.51787745579, 4167.27928087036, 4601.85525836751, 1821.2034900383, 2189.72791435169, 3042.30535389526, 2807.6043315874, 3503.01431953652, 3388.13238117821, 2313.12951730274, 2467.59594581105, 4330.00215695838, 1549.09273602756)
y <- c(920.68690954229, 1137.84149285619, 3714.79810142198, 525.975683495926, 4670.69955143504, 1493.68495554182, 1501.53384921405, 3588.98207281835, 3968.37860894073, 2296.76763280149, 4330.12427328142, 3765.98857808619, 1284.3150461877, 873.118502077055, 1483.53008725903, 815.412154986151, 4463.78018136535, 2968.50399111329, 698.224125591837, 2940.85602751641, 3878.15548230943, 1328.25283484688, 2784.55159286978, 4636.50519901311, 3881.31120249873, 817.73342724717, 3722.86686406547, 4002.31245250477, 3768.33450527414, 3154.10688698431, 2411.51176866728, 866.917134460099, 1396.35278812964, 818.293453576186, 722.016829126236, 2238.2347563775, 3138.27049629683, 1740.86153966934, 2525.9497400303, 4047.11508784272, 1569.12864914224, 1012.76266425136, 4322.80049028206, 981.94215394408, 4365.69066136564, 4532.95964795538, 1866.39445736013, 2121.89400568623, 1246.87146006084, 3985.44742807864, 3685.63400604974, 4105.59891177828, 2412.62820598686, 3828.64123889846, 3713.07718546435, 540.391421247504, 855.176561671193, 4137.8647389367, 4617.94816803374, 2632.57925475935, 1430.77932102484, 585.260671542401, 2791.60379735544, 662.995878839343, 1086.17685213414, 1508.33363397105, 3797.49220034402, 718.455348037237, 821.418280929054, 2320.73366733089, 3037.01065805153, 3744.25557757166, 1137.14346908283, 4043.14398706236, 3384.74681201601, 4193.99080611911, 3956.45258813361, 3960.0950899025, 1500.17773405924, 719.345768310553, 4665.91832227831, 2294.35505152451, 3130.20953126254, 3249.86842440019, 4185.34445315494, 1281.99666198422, 4702.59737079202, 1442.59945303309, 4104.62639132807, 4449.65179752112, 2649.72501474236, 1382.85732689515, 670.466846126166, 1200.25959688326, 930.085277226521, 900.999779024878, 802.132645649877, 683.43691692694, 873.658520876257, 1650.64502017811, 3418.34949699146, 1222.13071728263, 3409.402375469, 843.630081307405, 3998.21173386675, 4683.80520819962, 3676.33980631904, 2177.49853170284, 3325.67118471741, 862.401958786781, 2875.04148289356, 3926.44223954175, 4464.43685925494, 1705.96137858541, 2228.58688259817, 2858.88711631399, 2722.96159936358, 3465.44676305098, 3393.12321104936, 2179.31626722578, 2417.29268343776, 4306.71687173042, 1467.19383715601)

mean.se <- function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x)) # std. error of the mean, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2677859/684229
```

where elements of `x` and `y` correspond to each other.

Then we have group means and their standard errors:

```
> mean(x)
[1] 2583.535
> mean.se(x)
[1] 125.6576
> mean(y)
[1] 2537.709
> mean.se(y)
[1] 122.4061
```

Now, if we look at the pairwise difference and try to compare it to zero:

```
> mean(x-y)
[1] 45.82627
> sd(x-y)
[1] 112.3571
> mean.se(x-y)
[1] 10.1309
```

we see that if we use the **standard error of the difference** (`sd(x-y)`), the difference is not significant; whereas if we use the **standard error of the mean of the difference** (`mean.se(x-y)`), then it is significant.

Is this difference in direct correspondence to the unpaired vs paired t-test, respectively? Because what I see from t-test looks pretty similar (see below), I am just not sure if statistically and principially these things are linked together:

```
> t.test(x, y, paired = FALSE)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 0.26123, df = 243.83, p-value = 0.7941
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -299.7108  391.3633
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 2583.535  2537.709 

> t.test(x, y, paired = TRUE)

        Paired t-test

data:  x and y
t = 4.5234, df = 122, p-value = 1.422e-05
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 25.77114 65.88139
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
               45.82627
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the second part is YES: the paired t-test corresponds to the standard error of the mean of the difference. Proof: the formula for [paired t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Dependent_t-test_for_paired_samples) is

$$t = {{E(x - y) - 0}\over{s_{x-y}\over \sqrt n}}$$ and the denominator is exactly the standard error of the mean of the `x - y`.

The answer for the question if unpaired t-test corresponds to the standard error of the difference (`sd(x - y)`) is that it is more complicated. The formula for [independent two-sample unpaired t-test (see wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_two-sample_t-test):

$$t = {{E(x) - E(y)}\over {\sqrt{{s^2_x + s^2_y} \over n}}}$$

suggests that the relationship here is slightly different and more complicated.